# Various Type errors when trying to make this piece of Code work. What types does this function need?

Tags: haskell, types

Im trying to make this function work:

```
save dist dur speed
    |modulus<dur = True
    |otherwise   = False
    where modulus = mod (dist/(speed/3.6)) (2*dur)
```

depending on which type declaration I use, im hit with different errors. I intend to use the function on Ints.

I tried writing

```
save :: Int->Int->Int->Bool
```

and converting the Ints into more general numbers by doing

```
save :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
save dist dur speed
    |modulus<dur = True
    |otherwise   = False
    where ndist=fromIntegral dist
          ndur=fromIntegral dur
          nspeed=fromIntegral nspeed
          modulus = mod (ndist/(nspeed/3.6)) (2*ndur)
```

With this try I get the error:

```
 * No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'
    * In the second argument of `(/)', namely `(nspeed / 3.6)'
      In the first argument of `mod', namely `(ndist / (nspeed / 3.6))'
      In the expression: mod (ndist / (nspeed / 3.6)) (2 * ndur)
  |
8 |           modulus = mod (ndist/(nspeed/3.6)) (2*ndur)
  |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I hope You can tell me how to make this function work and perhaps how to write it in a normal way.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell's `mod` only works on Integral types, and `/` only works on Fractional.  No type is both, so you'll need to be explicit about where you want to convert.  One option is:

```hs
save :: Double -> Integer -> Double -> Bool
save dist dur speed
    |modulus<dur = True
    |otherwise   = False
    where modulus = mod (round (dist/(speed/3.6))) (2*dur)
```

If you want all the inputs to be the same type, you can insert additional conversions.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a mod for Non-Integral Types too?

Comment: @Laurens Also note that doing `if something then True else False` is exactly the same as doing `something`. So in your case you only need `save dist dur speed = modulus < dur`

Comment: Not that I know of.  I have this small function: `truncateSigFigsGeneric :: RealFrac a => Int -> a -> a
truncateSigFigsGeneric n f = (fromInteger $ round $ f * (10^n)) / (10.0^^n)
`